# how to tell SSIS not to hold data while being joined

Tags: sql-server, join, ssis

I am asking how to do something in SSIS that is a feature in datastage.

I am seeing a SSIS job where if I am going to perform a join or lookup, SSIS tries to "memorize" the entire datasets prior to the join. My datasets are too large for SSIS to 'memorize' and causes memory overloads.

In datastage, I can avoid this by having sort stages in front of the join stage, and the join stage monopolizes this by using a "sorted join", whereas the entire dataset isn't held in memory, but is immediately joined and sent ot the next stage while the join is in progress, saving memory.  the sort stage also allows me to sort during the source connector and just "say it's sorted".  Either way, the datasets are not held until fully memorized.  They get passed on when ajoin happens.

How do I accomplish this in SSIS? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I understood, you do not want SSIS to store the data in memory because the dataset is too large and its causing an error, right? In the Lookup Transform Task you can select how do you want SSIS to handle your data with Cache Mode (I worked with this in BIDS 2008). Basically you have 3 options:

- **Full Cache**: the database is queried and 'memorizes' the data **BEFORE** doing any transformation or insert into it.
- **Partial Cache**: uses a partial cache, and if no match is found, queries the database.
- **No Cache**: It does not maintain a Lookup cache, so it queries the database for every row proccessed.

You can find more detailed information about Lookup cache mode [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/10/18/lookup-cache-modes/)

Hope it was what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a lookup, you should be using a Merge Join transformation.

The Merge Join is partially blocking, meaning the incoming rows need to be sorted, and the output is only held up until either of the incoming keys have moved to a new value.

[This article](http://www.bimonkey.com/2010/10/the-merge-join-transformation/) explains how the Merge Join works way more exhaustively than I will.   If this link ever goes dead, just google "SSIS Merge Join Blocking".

But what you need to know is that your source components need to be sorted on the keys that you will them on.   Then the Merge Join will only "memorize" as much data as it needs for each possible JOIN combination, and then it will release them to the rest of the dataflow while it processes the next combination.

In other words, it does exactly what you are asking for.